# Wicket listview within a listview

Tags: listview, nested, html-lists, wicket, hierarchy

I am pretty new to Wicket so I'm probably making a horrible mistake here.

I am trying to add a listview to a listview but I receive an error, I know that this error has to do with the hierarchy of components and its because the hierarchy of the java file and html file are not the same. I just don't know how to solve it. Could someone give me some pointers?

relevant code (setting up listviews):

```
final ListView<MenuItem> subListView = new ListView<MenuItem>("menuSubView", new ArrayList<MenuItem>()) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<MenuItem> item) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
};

subListView.setRenderBodyOnly(true);
subListView.setReuseItems(true);

ListView<MenuItem> listView = new ListView<MenuItem>("menuView", menuItems) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<MenuItem> item) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = item.getModelObject();
    AjaxLink<MenuItem> aLink =  new AjaxLink<MenuItem>("menuItemLink") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    if(target != null) {
                        //DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
    };

    aLink.add(new Label("linkText", menuItem.getText()));
    item.add(aLink);
    item.add(subListView);
}
```

html:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <ul wicket:id="menuView">
        <li>
            <a href="#" wicket:id="menuItemLink" >
                <span wicket:id="linkText"></span>
            </a>
                <ul wicket:id="menuSubView">
                    <li>
                        <div wicket:id="subItemText"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

error:

> Unable to find component with id 'menuSubView' in [ListItem [Component
>   id = 0]]  Expected: 'viewerPanel:optionsMenu:menuView:0.menuSubView'.
>     Found with similar names:
>   'viewerPanel:optionsMenu:menuView:1:menuSubView'  MarkupStream:
>   [markup =
>   file:.../panels/menu/SimpleMenu.html
>
> </li> -->       , index = 9, current =  '' (line 0,
>   column 0)]    at
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1435)
>   ....

Thank you in advance for replying.

Kind regards,
Bram

Comment: Move the creation of the inner ListView 'subListView' into the populateItem() of the other ListView.

Comment: Thank you Bert! At least I don't have an error anymore but it seems pretty clustered in my opinion. Is this a good (or acceptable) way to go or do you think there's a better way?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable and actually it is the only thing you can do since you need to populate listview for each item of another listview. @Bram +1

Comment: @bert - you should make this an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: You should probably put the creation of the 'subListView' in a Panel and then just add that in the populateItem() of the main ListView. It would make everything a lot tidier.

Comment: @drobson What would that look like?